# How many credits (Republic credits or whatever) does a Death Star cost?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

How many credits (or standardized form of currency in *Star Wars*) would it cost to build a Death Star?

Comment: @RogueJedi The price of the Death Star was mentioned in the linked question, but none of the three sub-questions ask about it and the answer doesn't even mention the Death Star. I don't think this is a dupe.

Comment: I searched a similar question before ask and I couldnt find anything related, I think althoug is answered in the linked question is not easy to find for somebody that have the same doub.

Comment: @RogueJedi this certainly isn't a dupe of that question. What makes you think it might be? I don't see the Death Star mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wookieepedia cites [*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) (a canon reference book published in 2015) in stating that the [first](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star) and [second](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_II) Death Stars cost **over 1,000,000,000,000 (1 trillion) [galactic credits](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Credit)** each.

Comment: Disney >> Forbes. Never thought I'd say that...

Comment: Why Vader was not fired...?

Comment: @JeanPaul Vader would find your lack of faith...disturbing.

Comment: @JeanPaul - the new canon comic "Vader" has Palpatine addressing this issue w/ Vader

Comment: In an Empire ruling over billions -- if not trillions -- of people, that's chump change!

Answer (score 5):

If 1 galactic credit === 1 American dollar:

> $852,000,000,000,000,000

According to [forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/carolpinchefsky/2012/02/21/how-much-would-it-cost-to-build-the-death-star-from-star-wars/) at least.

I genuinely don't think I'll ever be able to afford one.

Comment: Yes quadrillions sounds more likely. Advanced aircraft cost in the billions, advanced aircraft carriers can cost up to a trillion. So the Forbes estimate of nearly 1 quintillion really sounds more to scale in my estimation.

Comment: see also https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/response/isnt-petition-response-youre-looking

Comment: This cost is for the steel alone, assuming that the Death Star is mostly made of steel. The cost for a modern battle aircraft can easily reach 500 millions; from which the cost of raw steel is a tiny pourcentage. Even at half of a million, this would make the cost of steel at about 0.1% of the overal cost; therefore, for the Death Star, you would have to multiply this number by a factor of 1000.  Furthermore, only one has been built; which means that you cannot distribute the research and development cost over multiple items; therefore increasing the overall cost by at least another 1000x.

Comment: To all this, you must add other costs, like the fact that all this must be build into space, that some materials must come from all over the galaxy, that everything must be kept secret and at the same time, that everyone and everything involved int this must be protected at multiple levels.  Therefore, the multiplication factor of 1 million (1000 x 1000) that I've mentionned in my previous comment  is probably a minimum and the real number should be at least 10 time bigger: 10 million times more than the cost of raw steel for such a marvelous single piece of technology.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VljtK.jpg

Comment: This is what happens when blood-thirsty Sith Lords win the Galactic Powerball Lottery.

These aren't the numbers you're looking for...

Comment: @SylvainL I wanna read your comments [but...](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starpolar/images/6/6b/Notime.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150225125846)