# What is the in-universe cost of an AT-AT?

Tags: star-wars

I need to know how many credits an [AT-AT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walker_(Star_Wars)#All_Terrain_Armored_Transport_(AT-AT)) costs?

I've searched but I can't find any resources or materials that tell me how much it costs.

Comment: Is someone running an RPG and this isn't in the sourcebooks? Seems like a pattern building here.

Comment: @radhil - The Star Wars RPG Sourcebook says that they're *NOT AVAILABLE FOR SALE*.

Comment: @Valorum - Are Death Stars for sale?  They made so many of them...

Comment: @Radhil - If you have to ask the price, you can't afford one, but [they're not cheap](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114651/how-many-credits-republic-credits-or-whatever-does-a-death-star-cost/114654#114654). Perhaps Sir would be more comfortable looking at this catalogue of used Republic-era Star Destroyers

Comment: This was a pretty tricky one to answer. They're not priced in any of the obvious sourcebooks

Answer (score 7):

The [Age of Rebellion Core Rulebook](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Age_of_Rebellion_Core_Rulebook) identifies the nominal purchase price of an AT-AT as (approx) 150,000 Imperial credits.

[image]

Given that they're described in other rulebooks as being *non-available to anyone outside the Imperial Military*, I would argue that they're not really purchasable openly, regardless of the size of your pocket-book and even as military surplus. You'd either have to get one on the black market or pay someone to steal one.